# selenium ElementNotVisibleException can't catch hidden elements

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am currently trying to make some user interface tests using selenium and I ran into this nice method (not sure anymore where I got it from..) which suppose to take care of not existing elements and hidden elements...

The problem lies in the second catch: the method keeps returning 'true' even though the element is not shown/hidden (visibility: hidden)

```
public boolean elementExists(By locator, WebDriver driver) {
    WebElement foo = null;
    try {
        foo = this.getElementByLocator(locator, 10, driver);
    } catch (TimeoutException te) {
        System.out
                .println("Timeout - Dieses Element konnte nicht gefunden werden: "
                        + locator.toString());
        return false;
    } 
    catch (ElementNotVisibleException env) {
        System.out
                .println("Dieses Element wurde gefunden, ist aber nicht sichtbar: "
                        + locator.toString());
        return false;
    }
    if (foo == null ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public WebElement getElementByLocator(By locator, int timeout,
        WebDriver driver) {
    System.out.println("Rufe Methode getElementByLocator: "
            + locator.toString());
    int interval = 5;
    if (timeout <= 20)
        interval = 3;
    if (timeout <= 10)
        interval = 2;
    if (timeout <= 4)
        interval = 1;
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class,
                    StaleElementReferenceException.class);
    WebElement we = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
            .presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
    return we;
}
```

Can anybody please tell me how I could modify this to be able to recognize that an existing element in hidden? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated
```

checks if an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible.

try using visibilityOfElementLocated instead. This checks that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.

more of this [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)

```
catch (ElementNotVisibleException env) {
```

I don't think that this is being thrown in your case. Anyway, if you were to interact with it and the element would be hidden - this would be thrown, but not on lookup.

EDIT:
Why so much code for so little benefit? This does the same:

```
   public boolean elementExists(By locator, WebDriver driver){
        return  (new WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
                .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator))) != null;
    }
```